# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory:E:\Selenium-Project\cucumberDemo\--plugin

Tags: selenium, cucumber

When I run a sample cucumber feature file, it's showing 
exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory: E:\Selenium-Project\cucumberDemo--plugin

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory: E:\Selenium-Project\cucumberDemo\--plugin
at cucumber.runtime.io.FileResourceIterator$FileIterator.<init>(FileResourceIterator.java:54)
at cucumber.runtime.io.FileResourceIterator.<init>(FileResourceIterator.java:20)
at cucumber.runtime.io.FileResourceIterable.iterator(FileResourceIterable.java:19)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.load(CucumberFeature.java:38)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.cucumberFeatures(RuntimeOptions.java:117)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:92)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:20)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Comment: provide code that you used instead of only exception

Comment: provide details for feature, step definition,Testrunner files and how you are executing??

Comment: we can also run only feature file. no test runner ,step defination,only sample feature file is throwing this exception.                                             Feature: Test LAZ scenario
 Scenario: Test Login with valid credentials
 Given Open Firefox and start application
 When I entered valid uname and upassword
 Then user should able to login successfully

Comment: Provide future file that you tried

Comment: I guess you are using Eclipse as IDE, did you installed all the required jar files and plugins?.

Comment: yes eclipse neon. i added all jar files.evenif installed this one also http://cucumber.github.com/cucumber-eclipse/update-site.                            its working fine  but now not working.

Comment: Feature: Test LAZ scenario                                                                 
 Scenario: Test Login with valid credentials
 Given Open Firefox and start application
 When I entered valid uname and upassword
 Then user should able to login successfully

Comment: Let me know which version of cucumber-java that you are using currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using cucumber-java 1.2.5, cucumber-junit 1.2.4 and junit 4.12 versions it was working fine.

Try with mentioned version and let me know if your issue resolved.

Comment: but now its showing  following  error                                                                                                                                                                                                                            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cucumber/runtime/ClassFinder

Comment: please list all jar files  that you are importing with versions. so I can help you more.

Comment: Due to jar mismatch i face this issue